# Flutter, send and get a value after modification in another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I would like to do the example below, but I'm getting null out of it!!!

Inside of a stateful widget and a scaffold I have a button where it has an event like:

```
onPressed: () {
                 Object json = {'xxx': xxx,};
                 Server_queries sq = Server_queries();
                 print(sq.post('register/', json).toString());

                 String holder = Server_queries().post('register/', json);
                 print(holder.toString());

                 ////Both of them shows 'Null'
              },
```

And here is my other class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


const String server_address = 'xxxx';

class Server_queries {
  String res;

  String post(String link, Object json) {
    var url = server_address + link;
    var body = jsonEncode(json);
    http
        .post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body)
        .then((http.Response response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
        res = jsonDecode(response.body).toString();
      } else {
        res = response.statusCode.toString();
      }
    });
    return res;
  }
```

Printing out res inside of the post function shows the response but the problem exists in the other class!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing your function to async will resolve your issue. For example

```
Future<String> post(String link, Object json) async {
  var url = server_address + link;
  var body = jsonEncode(json);
  http.Response response = await http
    .post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
  if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
    res = jsonDecode(response.body).toString();
  } else {
    res = response.statusCode.toString();
  }
  return res;
}
```

And in onPressed event use it like

```
onPressed: () async {
             Object json = {'xxx': xxx,};
             Server_queries sq = Server_queries();
             print(await sq.post('register/', json).toString());

             String holder = await Server_queries().post('register/', json);
             print(holder.toString());

             ////Both of them shows 'Null'
          },
```